# Using and dispose correctly MediaElement Net MAUI

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm developing a small android app using MAUI.

In this app i have a MediaElement from MAUI Community Toolkit.

I have two page; the home and about page.

i have put dispose operation for MediaElement in ContentPage_Unloaded :

```
 private void ContentPage_Unloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   mediaElement.Handler?.DisconnectHandler();
   mediaElement.Dispose();
 }
```

But this will be executed also when i navigate towards about page of my application.

When user switch again on home page MediaElement dont work anymore.

I also have tried to recreate object in ContentPage_Loaded :

```
private void ContentPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // i set source more later in code
 mediaElement ??= new MediaElement()
 {
  IsEnabled = true,
  IsVisible = false
  };
}
```

But in this way MediaElment cant work correctly (no sound play anymore)

I also have tried to destroy MediaElement in App.xaml, Page_Dissapearing event, but also here this event is recalled every time i navigate in about pages in my application.

So what is the right way to manage dispose of MediaElement to be executed only when i close the application?

Comment: I don't use MAUI so there may be details that I'm not aware of but I would assume that your issue with the `MediaElement` not playing sound after navigating back to the page is because what you're seeing is the old, disposed object, not the new one. `mediaElement ??= new MediaElement()` is only going to create a new object if `mediaElement` is null, but you haven't shown us any code that would cause that to be the case. Disposing an object doesn't mean that the variables no longer refers to that object. Set a breakpoint in that `Loaded` event handler and see whether a new object is created.

Comment: Thansk for reply jmcilhinney, i have debugged step by step; In loaded event, and a new mediaelement object is created, in ContentPage_Unloaded i set a dispose for current mediaElement object, so in ContentPage_Loaded this is null and the new is triggered

Comment: Disposing an object via a variable does not cause that variable to be set to `null`. I'm not sure what's going on in your app but that just doesn't happen. There may well be things about the MAUI lifecycle that I don't understand so I'll leave it to those with more expertise to speak with more authority on what is happening but I can tell you that what is not happening is `mediaElement.Dispose()` causing `mediaElement` to be `null`. My guess would be that the `ContentPage` itself is a new object so `mediaElement` defaults to `null`.

Comment: Once you dispose of the object it's done